# How can I speed up my PostgreSQL SELECT function that uses a list for its WHERE clause?

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization

I have a function SELECT that takes in a list of `symbol` of parameters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION api.stats(p_stocks text[])
RETURNS TABLE(symbol character, industry text, adj_close money, week52high money, week52low money, marketcap money,
pe_ratio int, beta numeric, dividend_yield character)
as $$
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.symbol) t1.symbol,
                            t3.industry, 
                            cast(t2.adj_close as money),
                            cast(t1.week52high as money),
                            cast(t1.week52low as money),
                            cast(t1.marketcap as money),
                            cast(t1.pe_ratio as int),
                            ROUND(t1.beta,2),
                            to_char(t1.dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%%')
                FROM api.security_stats as t1
                LEFT JOIN api.security_price as t2 USING (symbol) 
                LEFT JOIN api.security as t3 USING (symbol)
                WHERE symbol = any($1) ORDER BY t1.symbol, t2.date DESC
$$ language sql
PARALLEL SAFE;
```

I'm trying to speed up the initial query by adding indexes and other methods, it did reduce my query time by half the speed, but only when the list has ONE value, it's still pretty slow with more than one value.

For brevity, I've added the original select statement below, with only one symbol as a parameter, `AAPL`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (t1.symbol) t1.symbol,
                            t3.industry,
                            cast(t2.adj_close as money),
                            cast(t1.week52high as money),
                            cast(t1.week52low as money),
                            cast(t1.marketcap as money),
                            cast(t1.pe_ratio as int),
                            ROUND(t1.beta,2),
                            to_char(t1.dividend_yield * 100, '99D99%%')
                FROM api.security_stats as t1
                LEFT JOIN api.security_price as t2 USING (symbol)
                LEFT JOIN api.security as t3 USING (symbol)
                WHERE symbol = 'AAPL' ORDER BY t1.symbol, t2.date DESC;
```

Here are the details on performance:

```
                                                                              QUERY PLAN
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=71365.86..72083.62 rows=52 width=130) (actual time=828.301..967.263 rows=1 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=71365.86..72083.62 rows=287101 width=130) (actual time=828.299..946.342 rows=326894 loops=1)
         Sort Key: t2.date DESC
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 33920kB
         ->  Hash Right Join  (cost=304.09..25710.44 rows=287101 width=130) (actual time=0.638..627.083 rows=326894 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: ((t2.symbol)::text = (t1.symbol)::text)
               ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on security_price t2  (cost=102.41..16523.31 rows=5417 width=14) (actual time=0.317..2.658 rows=4478 loops=1)
                     Recheck Cond: ((symbol)::text = 'AAPL'::text)
                     Heap Blocks: exact=153
                     ->  Bitmap Index Scan on symbol_price_idx  (cost=0.00..101.06 rows=5417 width=0) (actual time=0.292..0.293 rows=4478 loops=1)
                           Index Cond: ((symbol)::text = 'AAPL'::text)
               ->  Hash  (cost=201.02..201.02 rows=53 width=79) (actual time=0.290..0.295 rows=73 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 17kB
                     ->  Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=4.98..201.02 rows=53 width=79) (actual time=0.062..0.252 rows=73 loops=1)
                           Join Filter: ((t1.symbol)::text = (t3.symbol)::text)
                           ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on security_stats t1  (cost=4.70..191.93 rows=53 width=57) (actual time=0.046..0.195 rows=73 loops=1)
                                 Recheck Cond: ((symbol)::text = 'AAPL'::text)
                                 Heap Blocks: exact=73
                                 ->  Bitmap Index Scan on symbol_stats_idx  (cost=0.00..4.69 rows=53 width=0) (actual time=0.029..0.029 rows=73 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((symbol)::text = 'AAPL'::text)
                           ->  Materialize  (cost=0.28..8.30 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=1 loops=73)
                                 ->  Index Scan using symbol_security_idx on security t3  (cost=0.28..8.29 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=1 loops=1)
                                       Index Cond: ((symbol)::text = 'AAPL'::text)
 Planning Time: 0.329 ms
 Execution Time: 973.894 ms
```

Now, I will take the same SELECT statement above and change the where clause to `WHERE symbol in ('AAPL','TLSA')` to replicate my original `FUNCTION` first mentioned.

EDIT: Here is the new test using multiple values, when I changed `work_mem` to 10mb:

```
                                                                      QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Unique  (cost=253542.02..255477.13 rows=101 width=130) (actual time=5239.415..5560.114 rows=2 loops=1)
   ->  Sort  (cost=253542.02..254509.58 rows=387022 width=130) (actual time=5239.412..5507.122 rows=430439 loops=1)
         Sort Key: t1.symbol, t2.date DESC
         Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 43056kB
         ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=160938.84..191162.40 rows=387022 width=130) (actual time=2558.718..3509.201 rows=430439 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: ((t1.symbol)::text = (t2.symbol)::text)
               ->  Hash Left Join  (cost=50.29..400.99 rows=107 width=79) (actual time=0.617..0.864 rows=112 loops=1)
                     Hash Cond: ((t1.symbol)::text = (t3.symbol)::text)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on security_stats t1  (cost=9.40..359.81 rows=107 width=57) (actual time=0.051..0.246 rows=112 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: ((symbol)::text = ANY ('{AAPL,TSLA}'::text[]))
                           Heap Blocks: exact=112
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on symbol_stats_idx  (cost=0.00..9.38 rows=107 width=0) (actual time=0.030..0.031 rows=112 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: ((symbol)::text = ANY ('{AAPL,TSLA}'::text[]))
                     ->  Hash  (cost=28.73..28.73 rows=973 width=26) (actual time=0.558..0.559 rows=973 loops=1)
                           Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 64kB
                           ->  Seq Scan on security t3  (cost=0.00..28.73 rows=973 width=26) (actual time=0.009..0.274 rows=973 loops=1)
               ->  Hash  (cost=99479.91..99479.91 rows=3532691 width=14) (actual time=2537.403..2537.404 rows=3532691 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 262144  Batches: 32  Memory Usage: 6170kB
                     ->  Seq Scan on security_price t2  (cost=0.00..99479.91 rows=3532691 width=14) (actual time=0.302..1347.778 rows=3532691 loops=1)
 Planning Time: 1.409 ms
 Execution Time: 5569.160 ms
```

I've managed to solve the problem by removing a `adj_close` from my original query. My function is now fast. Thank you for helping me point out the problem within my query planner.

Comment: Can you show the multi-symbol plan after you disable JIT (`set jit = off`) and disable parallel (`set max_parallel_workers_per_gather TO 0`)?

Comment: @jjanes, thank you for your comment. I've edited my original post.

Comment: You problem seems to lie in "Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 43048kB". This indicates Postgres needs disk i/o (about the slowest thing a computer is capable of doing) to sort your data. No index can overcome that. Try increasing work_mem setting in postgresql.conf.

Comment: Get the current setting for work_mem: SHOW work_mem; Changing work_mem for the current database connection (for testing for example): SET work_mem TO '10MB';

Comment: Thank you for your advices, I have increased work_mem to `10mb` for testing purposes. I've seem to increase the speed, however still not as fast as I'm expecting. Does the list parameter in the WHERE clause really slow down things that much? I have updated my OG post with the new benchmark for multiple values in symbols.

Comment: You still have an external sort even with 10mb and that takes about 2 seconds. Do you have an index on `api.security_price (symbol)`?

Comment: With further testing, removing the datapoint from `security_price` lowers the select to 1ms

Comment: Raise work_mem to 50MB or so, that’s the amount of data is has to sort

Comment: But removing "the datapoint from security_price" also removes sort criteria. Not a recommendation we could logically make and expect the same result.

Comment: @Belayer, yes you are right it's not the best method to proceed. When I meant remove the datapoint, I was talking about from the SELECT query. that datapoint is still in my table, and the sort criteria switched over to my date from the other tables inside the query. (I'm also worried off having my postgres workers consume too much memory as I only have a 1gb memory server. The original problem still persists however in my postgres Function. Not sure why I'm getting 4000+ ms for the same query in my function.

Comment: nvm, I managed to solve my function, forgot to remove the from `api.security_price` table query from my function.